# Ошибка при проверке переменной курсора - PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS NULL'?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```sql
FOR v_r_id IN (
     Запрос
  ) LOOP 

      IF v_r_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      ...
      END IF;
    ...
END LOOP;
```

Ошибка:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS NULL'

Почему возникает эта ошибка?

P.S. В цикле проход по одному столбцу.

Comment: v_r_id это record, а не атомарный тип данных и null быть не может, так же как и проверяться на null. видимо вы хотели написать `v_r_id.столбец IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Mike - да, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная `v_r_id` имеет тип данных `ROWTYPE`, который создаётся неявно из запроса в цикле `FOR-IN-LOOP` и является по сути PL/SQL типом данных `RECORD`.

Переменная с типом данных `RECORD` инстанцинируется сразу при обьявлении, не может быть `NULL` и не может быть проверена оператором `[NOT] IS NULL`. Присвоение такой переменной значения `NULL` означает, что всем полям этой переменной будет присвоено значение `NULL`, но не самой переменной.
Проверять на `NULL` имеет смысл только значения полей таких переменных:

```
IF v_r_id.id IS NOT NULL THEN ...
```

Это одно из основных отличий PL/SQL типа данных `RECORD` от SQL объектных типов данных.

В заключениe, небольшй пример для закрепления материала:

```sql
create or replace type ot is object (id number, val number);
/
declare 
    type rt is record (id number, val number);
    r rt := null;
    o ot := null;
begin null;
    if o is null then null; end if; -- ok
    --if r is null then null; end if; --PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS NULL' 
    if r.id is null then null; end if; --ok
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```